# Can't access object parent type if some parent object along the way was in array

Tags: unity, c#, code-reflection

[image: Fild Info Method]

I use this method to get type of the object the field was declared via reflection.
(f.e.) this time it's field at index `[5]` - `activePlaybackAudioArchive`.

If along the way the object/objects in hierarchy was placed in array it produces - 
`[1] Array` and `[2] data[0]`. Strangely the `[SerializeField] private AudioPlayerData[] _audioPlayerData` is the array, why it shows in hierarchy below this variable is unusual to me.

Is there a good way to deal with this problem, or omit the indices like `[1] and [2]`? Or maybe there is a proper way to get `fieldNames` that wouldn't include `Array` like types into path?

[image: Property path]

Comment: I wouldn't like to have exceptions that are omitted because they can appear out of nowhere, so I didn't bother making them because it would be a faster fix and look like code smell. But this is `reflection`, so I guess there may not be another way but to parse strings in `fieldNames`  array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Get parent field info]

```
public static readonly string[] PATH_FIELD_NAMES_EXCEPTIONS_SUBSRTINGS = { "Array", "data[" };

private static bool IsException(string fieldName)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < TypeExtensions.PATH_FIELD_NAMES_EXCEPTIONS_SUBSRTINGS.Length; j++)
        if (fieldName.Substring(0, TypeExtensions.PATH_FIELD_NAMES_EXCEPTIONS_SUBSRTINGS[j].Length) == TypeExtensions.PATH_FIELD_NAMES_EXCEPTIONS_SUBSRTINGS[j])
            return true;

    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Search to top of the hierarchy via fieldNames
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type"></param>
/// <param name="fieldNames"></param>
/// <returns>Parent object FieldInfo || null if has no parent</returns>
public static FieldInfo GetParentObjectFieldInfoViaPath(this Type type, string[] fieldNames)
{
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        //if (TypeExtensions.IsException(fieldNames[i]))
        //  continue;
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            type = type.GetElementType();

            i += 2;
        }

        fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldNames[i], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsArray && i + 3 >= fieldNames.Length)
            break;

        type = fieldInfo.FieldType;
    }

    return fieldInfo;
}
```

Here is a quick workaround, cheat :) Check if it's an array, if it is, then skip 2 steps `(Array, data[n])`. Then the magic method - `GetElementType()`  and everything is fine.

Comment: Please paste code as text, not as images. That keeps it searchable, copy & paste friendly, and accessible to users via screen readers.